# MouseClick event handler in custom inherited class

Tags: event-handling, mouse

I wanted to create a custom PictureBox class inherited from PictureBox.

```
public partial class Custom : PictureBox
{
    public Custom()
    {
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(20, 20);
        this.Image = WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Resources.icon;
    }

    private void Custom_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {

        }
    }       
}
```

I also created contextMenuStrip but cannot atach it to my MouseClick event. If I try to use

`contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);`

I get the error that contextMenuStrip1 does not exist in current context. How to handle this event?

Comment: contextMenuStrip1 is probably defined in your form's code, so it isn't available in the custom picturebox. You have to create a new one in this class to use it.

Answer (score 0):

The way I handled this is failry simple. First of all i had to create delegate to handle MouseClick event.

```
this.MouseClick +=Custom_MouseClick;
```

Then create menu object and fill all the needed information

```
    private void Custom_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            ContextMenuStrip menu = new ContextMenuStrip();

            ToolStripMenuItem addItem = new ToolStripMenuItem();
            addItem.Name = "AddMenuItem";
            addItem.Text = "Add";
            menu.Items.Add(addItem);

            ToolStripMenuItem editItem = new ToolStripMenuItem();
            editItem.Name = "EditMenuItem";
            editItem.Text = "Edit";
            menu.Items.Add(editItem);

            menu.Show(Cursor.Position);
            menu.ItemClicked += menu_ItemClicked;
        }
    }
```

And then, in order to make my menu work I had to create another delegate to handle ItemClicked menu event.

```
    void menu_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        [code]
    }
```